# Excel VBA Dictionary of Dictionaries with potential duplicate keys

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have a dictionary of transactions (each defined by a dynamic unique id) with each transaction its own dictionary. Each transaction might have several sub-transactions only containing a currency and amount that need to be stored as individual records. Does anyone have any thoughts on the best way to implement this without using a basic integer (e.g. count+1) as the key?

Data should look like this where dictParent a1 will contain 4 subdictionaries:

Transaction     Currency     Amount

a1              USD          25000

a1              USD          30000

a1              USD          25000

a1              EUR          10000

My code so far:

```
if not dictParent.exists(strCurrency) then
   set dictTemp = new dictionary
   dictTemp.add key:=strCurrency, item:=amount
   dictParent.add key:=XXXX, item:=dictTemp
else
   ....
end if
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The dictionary by its definition cannot contain duplicates. So you may consider creating a dictionary of arrays. Having parent dictionary (key: a1, item: array that contains a list of transactions)

Comment: `TransactionID` + `RowId`: `Key:= XXXX & "|" & currentRow & "|" & strCurrency` - this way you can identify each item in the sub-transaction by splitting the key by `"|"` (or `Date`, or `Time` instead of `RowId`)

Comment: @paulbica exactly - smart and simple

Comment: Really good suggestions, thanks!